# Checking if upload image from iphone

Tags: php, ios, forms

I have problem when i try to upload picture from iphone its always return false
but if i try from my computer its work fine

I use this function

```
   function IsFileUploaded($field_name)
  {
if(count($_FILES) > 0)
{
    if(empty($_FILES[$field_name]['name']))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field_name]['tmp_name']))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
    }
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: have you tried echoing each field to see what `if` statement is failing? cuz that would be the first thing i would do.

Comment: yes i try it and still

Comment: its say that no picture was upload but from the computer its work fine so the problem is not the function

Comment: obviously it would still fail bro, but at least you would have an idea of WHY it fails. what is the count of `$_FILES`? what is `$_FILES[field_name]['name']` value? do some basic debugging man.